# MVC - How to dynamically set @class in Html.ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

How can I dynamically set @class in an ActionLink?

I want to do

```
@Html.ActionLink("Pricing", "Index", "Pricing", new { PageIndex = 2, @(ViewBag.PageIndex == 2 ? @class="" : @class="ActiveMenuItem" )}, null)
```

But the runtime blows up on my syntax.

Comment: hang on... is "class" meant to be the html attribute? and is "PageIndex" action parameter? if these are different then I may need to adjust my answer

Comment: @musefan - Yup you are correct.  I'll update your answer to reflect what I actually ended up using.  Its very close to your suggestion so you keep credit.

Comment: I have updated to show how you can still use an ActionLink if desired

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you want "class" to be an HTML attribute and "PageIndex" to be an action parameter you can do this instead:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Pricing")?PageIndex=2" class="@(ViewBag.PageIndex == 2 ? "ActiveMenuItem" : "")">Pricing</a>
```

MUSEFAN EDIT:

You can still use an ActionLink like this...

```
@Html.ActionLink("Pricing", "Index", "Pricing", new {PageIndex = 2}, new {@class = ViewBag.PageIndex == 2 ? "" : "ActiveMenuItem"})
```

Answer (score 4):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Pricing", "Index", "Pricing", 
new { PageIndex = 2, @class = (ViewBag.PageIndex == 2)? "" : "ActiveMenuItem" },
 null)
```